# Which properties can I check for in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When using TypeScript, I realized that I don't fully understand how property checking works. In the example below I do not understand why checking for `.bold` works but but checking for `.type` doesn't.

```
type CustomText = {
    bold: boolean;
};

type TitleElement = { type: 'title'; children: string };

type Element = TitleElement | CustomText;

const el: Element = {
  bold: true,
}

if (!el.bold) {
  console.log("does not have bold")
}

if (!el.type) { // <- compiler error
  console.log("does not have type")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like, Typescript already knows that the element you have entered is of what type (`CustomText`) because it is statically assigned in your code. Had it been something dynamic, TS would have complained for both.

For example:

```
const getElem = () => {
  if(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)%2)
   {
      const x : TitleElement = { name: 'title', children: 'x' };
      return x;
   } 
  else{
      const x : CustomText = { bold: false };
      return x;
 
  }
}

type CustomText = {
    bold: boolean;
};

type TitleElement = { name: 'title'; children: string };

type Element2 = TitleElement | CustomText;

let el: Element2 = getElem();

if (!el.bold) {

  console.log("does not have bold")
}

if (!el.name) { // <- compiler error
  console.log("does not have type")
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygUQDYILYwLwwBQCUOAfDAN4BQMMAlgGZ4CyAhlABYB0dqIIATniatOfZmAAmIDIRgAqGAEYADEQDUiggFIATASrVK1IzFCRYADxgAuGABUaUdGkwIwsXGRhhmGBDYDkUA7o-gA0Jmw0qOJ8rgHm-jAAvgDc+saxUACufGAw5mlGSTD6CKgQCIbGJuDQ+dYwAMJZ0FK2CObu5DAARiDRNnTM5QjJhdWZOXkFVPpJFPMUUACeAA6jza0Y7Z045Om9-eI2ff0IYmmpFEtro-aOCM6+bnue3r4BQQ-+KRFRMXEYNA+DQwHAxtcVusYE9XFBtHt7k50M9YAAfJotKBtDpQNIUdCwMo2WFuBG4RAoFGEfH0fAAQjKHD60SIlH0pggZw4PDgeAARJIEBAvCBYGxmAA3UYs8T8vSLOl4RmoDjvBBsmAAei1MAAPABaGoYVZRBB8GDmvj8Dm1bm8gVCkVgMUwCXSmBQhDyhZAA)

The purpose of Union is that it allows properties from all the union participants. You can easily access any property present in **both** `CustomText` and `TitleElement`. TS should throw an error and it will . If you do something like below, TS will throw errors in both the if conditions.

```
type CustomText = {
    bold: boolean;
    both : string;
};

type TitleElement = { name: 'title'; children: string, both : string; };

type Element2 = TitleElement | CustomText;

const el: Element2 = {
  bold: true,children: 'sing' 
}

if (!el.bold) {
  console.log("does not have bold")
}

if (!el.name) { // <- compiler error
  console.log("does not have type")
}

if (!el.both) { // <- compiler error
  console.log("does not have type")
}
```

This happens cause now again TS is not sure of the **type** of `Element2`, and it cannot allow you to access a property not present in both.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYBUIA9hQLxQDeAUFGVAEbIA2AJgFyXI0QCGAdgNynlXAAWURkgBOAS3YBzbgF9uxUJCjoxwahACi61BHa4ChKO1Y7GAcmCr1ZzlADG-MXRG7hwcVIA0TAUKiiJaSg5YgVwaC0IHT0AJnxlK01tXVwAH1hEFAxsYHk7ZHYkKAhqRkjo4DiDHio6Rnc4CE8HJ1oXdnMEQLMoYhlQsQAzKAAKAEISgDpa2gBKIh58wpZJ6mRJEYAiWmQIBCNkXH5WADdoGc3ZvoHh8anjHXnDAHpnqAAeAFp7NDAnCBExREImQIkWBQQKzWG22u327EOUGOZygiggl2uxCGowm1Gmh34Tygrw+33yqD+6kBAJBYLIS0h6lW6y2Oz2ByOp2gaIxMiAA)

Comment: I changed `type` to `name` cause type is keyword in TS and i felt weird using it. It doesn't matter though

Comment: Changed Elem to Elem2 cause the playground was having an issue, since Element is a DOM type

Comment: This helps a lot. Do you know whats the best way to narrow down the type in cases like this? Let's say I want to say: "If the elment has the property `name` and the name is "Bob" return `true`. If it has no property `name` return false?

Comment: TypeScript does not allow me to access anything that could narrow down the type.

Comment: I hope you are getting the object value dynamically. What is the point if you already know the value in your code right. I hope this is only to showcase the issue. If you want you can use the `in` keyword

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygUQDYILYwLwwBQCUOAfDAN4BQMMAlgGZ4CyAhlABYB0dqIIATniatOfZmAAmIDIRgAqGAEYADEQDUiggFIATASrVK1IzFCRYADxgAuGABUaUdGkwIwsXGRhhmGBDYDkUA7o-gA0Jmw0qOJ8rgHm-jAAvgDc+saxUACufGAw5mlGSTD6CKgQCIbGJuDQ+dYwAMJZ0FK2CObu5DAARiDRNnTM5QjJhdWZOXkFVPpJFPMUUACeAA6jza0Y7Z045Om9-eI2ff0IYmmpFEtro-aOCM6+bnue3r420Hw0YHApEVEYnEYF8fnAxtcVusYE9XFBtHt7k50M9YAAfJotKBtDpQNIUdCwMo2WFuBG4RAoFGEfH0fD+PrRRI-GBlGAAMnZrNQHEZ4hw2FwQxGREo+lMEDOHB4cDwACJJAgIF4QLA2MwAG6jPlyvSLOl4fzvBDMvJszncjjGgW4QItdV8fyimAAehdMAAPABaGoYVZRBB8Vl8Pj8cW1KUy+WK5VgVUwdVamBQhC6hZAA